# training model on random samples from a large dataset

Tags: deep-learning, lstm, mini-batch-gradient-descent

I have a huge data set(More than 1 million data points).My dataset is text. i am doing NER on it to identify few entities. if i randomly choose 100 data points from the total data set and train my model(LSTM), will this yield good results? i will be running for `20k` random batches. Does this approximate the data properly or do i need to run for more number of batches than the total number of datapoints?

Answer (score 2):

Depends entirely on your data, if your variables are mostly numerical then you can get by with small samples. If however you have a lot of categorical variables you need to make sure that each category of every variable is well represented in the subsample. If they are all numerical I would go for 1000 data points repeated 1000 times.

Comment: i updated my question. my data is mostly text data

Comment: Then it depends on your number of entities and how un/balanced they are, I would go with `number of entities * 100` for sample size.

Comment: are you sure....

Comment: Without more information on your data it's anybodies guess how big the sample needs to be.

Comment: No, i meant (entities * 100), this is not a category classification. its kind of sequence prediction.

Comment: You are identifying entities (words) and classifying them into categories. In this case the categories are your expected number of entities, that is how many categories you expect will be present in your sample.

Comment: and each category depends on the previous word's classification. i am just extracting a names from the text. so, i really can't just take 1*100 data points.Also, there could be multiple names inside a single datapoint.